# invalidStateError for second time screenshare on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, screensharing

I would like to use Screensharing in Chrome. 
I mainly followed this [example](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/Pluginfree-Screen-Sharing) and created the extension to get the deviceId to use it in getUserMedia.

The first time I start, I get the stream of the screen and seems to work fine. But when I stop it by running the following code

```
_localScreenStream.getTracks().forEach(function (track) {
        track.stop();
    });
```

and then try to regain access to the screen stream I get an InvalidStateError.

An whole code example can you find [here](https://github.com/DasPartyEinhorn/basicScreenShare)

It seems that I don't give all recources free or something, but I don't find what exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chromeMediaSourceId is not reusable, you need to ask the user again.

Comment: Thank you very much. 
The Script I copied for the communication to the extension stores the sourceId globally and reuses it. So I had to set it to null when closing screen sharing.